# Inhomogeneous wave equation - a reference

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

Consider the inhomogeneous wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-\Delta u=\rho(x,t),$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $\Delta=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$ is the Laplacian, $\rho$ is a given function.

This equation has non-unique solutions.

> However I have heard that if one assumes in addition some decay of a solution at spatial infinity then solution becomes unique and is given by an explicit formula.
>   I would be interested to have a precise statement with all the assumptions and a reference. The case $n=3$ is particularly interesting to me.

I guess this material should be very standard, but I am not a specialist.

**ADDED:** Let me state my question more precisely. In Feynman's lectures in physics, Ch. 21 $\S$ 3, there is given a solution of the above wave equation for $n=3$ as follows (in different notation):
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\rho(y,t-|x-y|)}{|x-y|}dy.$$
It is implicity assumed  that the integral converges. To discard other solutions Feynman appeals to physical intuition. **I am wondering which mathematical conditions should be imposed on the solutions in order to get the above solution only.** Here no initial conditions are used apparently, only some decay at infinity (but it is not clear to me exactly).

Comment: Not even the ODE $y'=0$ has a unique solution. Additional conditions are needed, for the wave equation they are called initial conditions. If you add them, the behaviour at infinity has no influence. Maybe you should read some introductory course on this topic

Comment: Yes, additional conditions are necessary.  This is what I said- read the question again.  My question is what these additional conditions are.  Another part of my question is what is a reference to such an introductory course where the conditions are formulated explicitly.

Comment: This is treated in most PDE textbooks; Evans' textbook has it in one of the early chapters. The solution operator for the inhomogeneous problem can be constructed from that of the homogeneous, initial value problem using Duhamel's principle. // Alternatively, I think it is also treated in Chapter 1 of Sogge's _Nonlinear Wave Equations_ and one of the early chapters of Shatah and Struwe's _Geometric Wave Equations_.

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona: I added a comment to my post to clarify my question.

Comment: RE your edit: the "initial condition" used here is actually a scattering type condition. It is saying that the solution has no incoming radiation from past (null) infinity. For $\rho$ with sufficiently fast space-time decay, this solution can be picked out as the unique one such that $\lim_{v \to \infty} vu(t - v, x - \omega v) = 0$ (for all $t,x,\omega$; here $\omega \in \mathbb{S}^2$). I think the keyword to search for is "Sommerfeld radiation condition".

Comment: The hint given by @WillieWong should give you the information you need. However, there's a subtlety: due to its importance in electromagnetism and microwave engineering, you'll probably find out that the [Sommerfeld radiation conditions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Radiation_conditions) are usually stated for the Helmholtz equation, which is an elliptic PDE. This is not a mistake: the standard wave equation transforms in to this equation by considering the so called time harmonic fields.

Comment: @willie, the far field condition is not a decay condition. But you know this. What are we talking about precisely? MKO seems to be unaware of the basics of the Cauchy problem, so he should probably start with that. Evans is a good reference

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona: I try to read the tea-leaves and guess what MKO is looking for based on what little I remember of Feynman's lectures. When $\rho$ has compact space-time support, every solution to the wave equation can be written as the sum of the formula that Feynman gave plus a free wave. If I squint and pretend MKO remembered incorrectly about "decay and spatial infinity" and in fact is referring to "some asymptotic condition", then the far field condition (you can read it as "size $o(v^{-1})$ relative to null foliation") does the job. (Yes, lots of guess work. So comment, not answer.)

Comment: @WillieWong : I am trying to understand the formula for electromagnetic field created by moving charges in Feynman’s book.  It is reduced to solution of the wave equation with some extra conditions which are precisely the content of my question.

Comment: i think that the following link will be useful for the purposes of the OP: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node7.html