# Maxwell equations as Euler-Lagrange equation without electromagnetic potential

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, physics

In (mathematical) physics many equations of motion can be interpreted as Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations. The Maxwell equation for electromagnetic (EM) field (say in vacuum and in absence of charges) seems to me quite unusual in comparison to examples known in classical mechanics. This is a system of first order PDE on 6 components of EM field. To get the Lagrangian density, one takes the first pair of the Maxwell equations and deduces from it existence of electromagnetic potential. Substituting the potential into the second pair of Maxwell equations, one gets second order equations for the potential. They can be presented as EL-equations for the potential.

**I am wondering if there is a way to present the Maxwell equations as an EL-equation in terms of electromagnetic field only rather than potential.**

I think I can prove that this is impossible if one requires in addition that the Lagrangian density is quadratic in fields and their first derivatives and invariant under the Poincare group.

**ADDED 1:** By the Maxwell equations I mean
$$\operatorname{div}\vec B=\operatorname{div} \vec E=0,\, \operatorname{rot}\vec E=-\frac{1}{c}\dot{\vec B},\, \operatorname{rot}\vec B=\frac{1}{c}\dot{\vec E}.$$
Thus I am looking for a Lagrangian depending on $\vec E,\vec B$ as independent fields and their derivatives such that the EL-equation is equivalent to all these equations.

**ADDED 2:** Let me reformulate my question on the language of some of the answers and comments below. The standard approach to interpret Maxwell equations as EL-equation in electrodynamics is as follows. One selects out of 8 Maxwell equations four equations and declares them to be constrains, and the other four - equations of motions. One considers the variations of the action functional $\int L$ only in the class of electromagnetic fields $(\vec B,\vec E)$ satisfying the constrains. Its extrema recover the four equations of motion. This separation of the Maxwell equations into two halves seems to me to be artifical and different from all other examples I know. I am wondering if there is a way to consider all 8 Maxwell equations on equal footing for this purpose.

Comment: I suppose you are aware of Jackson's book on classical electrodynamics and the Lagrangian density relation (12.85), p.599, 3rd edition ? And you are not satisfied by this, due to the the second summand $\frac{1}{c}j_\alpha A^\alpha$ ?

Comment: x-posted on physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/603014/84967

Comment: If you are going to think of the electromagnetic field $F_{\alpha \beta}$ as an arbitrary two-form (as opposed to the curvature of a connection one-form $A_\alpha$), without any other additional fields present, then any Euler-Lagrange equation can only achieve six out of the eight Maxwell equations at best. If however you constrain $F_{\alpha \beta}$ to be a curvature, then the Yang-Mills Lagrangian $\frac{1}{2} \int F^{\alpha \beta} F_{\alpha \beta}$ works just fine, providing the four of the eight Maxwell equations not coming from curvature forms being closed.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou: In this post I explicitly suppose that there are no charges, i.e. no term $j_{\alpha}A^{\alpha}$.

Comment: @TerryTao: Your first sentence sounds to be in the right direction. However I do not understand the following example. If one considers the standard Lagrangian $\frac{1}{2}\int F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is any (not necessarily closed) 2-form, then the EL-equation is 6 equations $\vec E=\vec B=0$ (equivalently $F_{\mu\nu}=0$). It is much stronger than 8 Maxwell equations.

Comment: To specify the EL equations one needs to select both a Lagrangian and the set of constraints (the latter giving Lagrange multiplier terms in the EL equations).  As you say, standard Lagrangian plus no constraints gives too strong a set of equations; but standard Lagrangian plus the constraint of being closed (or a curvature) recovers the Maxwell equations.  I'm pretty sure the Maxwell equations can't be generated from 6 or fewer differential equations (though formally proving this would require some nontrivial differential algebra), so one cannot get Maxwell on the nose from unconstrained EL.

Comment: @TerryTao: " one cannot get Maxwell on the nose from unconstrained EL." This is what my original question was about.

Comment: Basically there is a differential algebra question to be answered here: what is the minimal number of generators for the differential ideal generated by the Maxwell equations (viewed as an ideal in the differential algebra generated by $E,B$ and its derivatives?).  The equations themselves form an eight-element set of the ideal, and this I believe is minimal, but proving this requires some non-trivial differential algebra (the ideal does not appear to be a "complete intersection", so naive degree of freedom counting doesn't give adequate bounds).

Comment: ... actually, I withdraw this belief; since we are working over the reals, one could combine the eight Maxwell's equations into a single equation by taking a sum of squares of each of the eight equations.  So some other means would be needed to definitively rule out Maxwell's equations having an unconstrained EL formulation.

Answer (score 13):

Yes indeed, the Maxwell's equations are Euler-Lagrange equations. And this is quite interesting. Let me give here a presentation within Special Relativity, in which the light speed is set to $c=1$. The ambiant space is therefore a Minkowski space $\mathbb R^{1+3}$ with metric $dt^2-d{x_1}^2-d{x_2}^2-d{x_3}^2$. I restrict myself to the case of a vacuum.

The electromagnetic field is by definition a closed two-form $\Omega$. The components of the field can be retrieved, in a given coordinates frame, by
$$\Omega=\vec E\cdot dt\times dx+\vec B\cdot(dx\times dx).$$
The constraint $d\Omega=0$ writes
$$\partial_t\vec B+{\rm curl}_x\vec E=0,\qquad{\rm div}_x\vec B=0.$$

The rest of the Maxwell's equations are obtain by writing
$$\delta\int\int L(\Omega)dxdt=0,$$
still under the constraint that the variations of $\Omega$ are compatible with the closedness. Writing $L$ as a function of $(\vec B,\vec E)$, we obtain
$$\partial_t\vec D-{\rm curl}_x\vec H=0,\qquad{\rm div}_x\vec D=0,\qquad(\dagger)$$
where
$$\vec D=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\vec E},\qquad\vec H=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\vec B}.$$
An important point is that $L$ must be invariant under Lorentz transformation. This translates the following way: there exists a function $\ell$ of two scalar variables only, such that
$$L(\Omega)=\ell\left(\frac12(\vec E^2-\vec B^2),\vec E\cdot\vec B\right).$$
For instance, the choice $L=\frac12(\vec E^2-\vec B^2)$ yields the standard, linear Maxwell's equations (in which $D=E$ and $H=-B$).

The energy density is a partial Legendre transform,
$$W=\vec D\cdot\vec E-L.$$
The Poynting vector is $\vec E\times\vec H$. It also equals $\vec D\times\vec B$. The fact that both formulas give the same quantity is equivalent to the Lorentz invariance.

**Edit**. Here are some of the details. The variational principle $\delta{\cal L}=0$, where ${\cal L}(\Omega)=\int\int L(\Omega)dxdt$, means that
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0}\int\int L(\Omega+\epsilon\alpha)dxdt=0$$
for every closed $2$-form $\alpha$. Equivalently, we have
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0}\int\int L(\Omega+\epsilon d\beta)dxdt=0$$
for every $1$-form (say smooth, compactly supported) $\beta$. Let us write $\beta=\phi dt-\vec A\cdot dx$, then $d\beta=(\partial_t\vec A+\nabla\phi)\cdot dt\times dx+{\rm curl}\vec A \cdot dx\times dx$. We therefore have
$$\int\int(\vec H\cdot{\rm curl}\vec A+\vec D\cdot(\partial_t\vec A+\nabla\phi))dxdt=0$$
for every test function $\phi$ and field $\vec A$. This gives $\partial_t\vec D-{\rm curl}\vec H=0$ and ${\rm div}\vec H=0$.

**Edit**. In a recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01448), I explore a variant of the variational principle, in which the admissible variations run over the same class as $\Omega$, modulo pullback composition by a diffeomorphism: $\delta\Omega=\Omega-\phi^*\Omega$. This is narrower than the additive perturbation considered above. The resulting equations ar interesting. We don't obtain the full ($\dagger$), but we do obtain the conservation of energy
$$\partial_tW+{\rm div}(\vec E\times\vec H)=0,$$
and that of momentum, which are perhaps more natural.

Comment: I think the main point of my question is that $L=\frac{1}{2}(E^2-B^2)$ does NOT give Maxwell equations. It does not contain derivatives of $\vec E,\vec B$ at all. Hence if one varies this $L$ one gets 0 order equation $\vec E=\vec B=0$. To get Maxwell equtions one has to assume that  $\vec E,\vec B$ are not arbitrary, but are first derivatives of another field called potential.

Comment: @makt. It is true that $L$ does not contain derivatives. But remark that if it did, then the E.-L. equations would be second order, while the Maxwell's E. are first-order only. The point is that the constraint $d\Omega=0$ does involve derivatives. Please do the calculations by yourself.

Comment: Indeed, at the level of the classical $\vec{E} $ and $\vec{B} $, there is no strict need for the potentials - one merely has to properly take into account the constraints on the dynamics, very nice. Only when one couples a quantum particle to the electromagnetic field, the Bohm-Aharonov effect appears - and suddenly the potentials appear to be more than just an artifice.

Comment: @DenisSerre: There is an abuse of terminilogy. For my $d\Omega=0$ is not a constrain but a part of Maxwell equations as it is common in physics. It encodes, in particular, the Faraday induction law. For me electromagnetic field is a pair $\vec E,\vec B)$ without any constrains. Thus I am looking for a  Lagrangian suth that its EL equation would imply the equation $d\Omega=0$.

Comment: @DenisSerre: I have added a related explanation to the post.

Comment: @makt. As you probably know, the Faraday induction law and the  equation ${\rm div}\vec B=0$ (there does not exist magnetic monopoles) are absolute. They remain the same whatever the context : in presence of charges, or in nonlinear models. Besides, the electric and magnetic components $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ are not absolute. They are relative, as they transform altogether along a Lorentz change of coordinates. Only the two-form $\Omega$ makes sense. Physics tells you that it is a closed form, period.

Comment: @makt - div $\vec{E} =$ div $\vec{B} =0$ are manifestly not dynamical equations, but constraint equations - they do not contain time derivatives. As such, they can of course not be derived from the Euler-Lagrange equations of an action functional of the form $S=\int L dt$.

Comment: @DenisSerre: Faraday induction law is different: $rot\vec E=-\frac{1}{c}\dot{\vec B}$. But it is not important. I agree that physics tells that $\Omega$ is closed. Physics also tells all other Maxwell equations as well. So what? I do not understand what does it mean that "only two-form $\Omega$ makes sense. Lorentz invariance was not known to Maxwell but was discovered later as a symmetry of Maxwell equations. $\vec E,\vec B$ also make perfect physical and mathematical sence.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: I have an objection: Lagrangian may contain space derivatives of $\vec E,\vec B$. Anyway I would be happy to see a more precise mathematical statement why without constrains it is impossible to get a positive answer to my question in the post.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: Furthermore if one considers $div\vec E=div\vec B=0$ as constrains, this is different from the common constrains equivalent to $d\Omega =0$ in the notation of Denis Serre.

Comment: @makt. I see that to convince you, I have to carry out more details. See my edits in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @makt - Indeed, there are different ways of looking at this which we shouldn't confuse. Based on your invocation of classical mechanical examples, I was taking the point of view of a fixed Lorentz frame, in which time has a definite meaning, and there is a clear distinction between dynamical and constraint equations (we could translate everything into Hamiltonian language, where all this is even more manifest). Then, the degrees of freedom are $\vec{E} (x)$, $\vec{B} (x)$ at every $x$, and they have a time evolution. So, in this point of view, no relativity, but a definite role of time ...

Answer (score 10):

There is a trivial sense in which the answer is "yes": the solutions to the Maxwell equations are (formally, at least) the global minimisers to the functional

$$ \int\int |\mathrm{div} E|^2 + |\mathrm{div} B|^2 + |\mathrm{rot} E + \frac{1}{c} \dot{B} |^2 + |\mathrm{rot} B - \frac{1}{c} \dot{E} |^2\ dx dt.$$

I would suppose you consider this as cheating, but in order to rule this sort of degenerate answer out you would need to formulate your question with more mathematical precision.

Comment: Is this example ruled out by requiring Lorentz invariance?

Comment: Hmm, good question.  There are no positive definite Lorentz-invariant inner products on 4-vectors, so this construction wouldn't work directly, but it's hard to see how to rule out some more sophisticated example of this form (involving various derivatives of the Maxwell equations) that would be both Lorentz invariant and minimized by the solutions to Maxwell.

Comment: @TerryTao You're almost cheating in the spirit of Feynman's universal law of nature ;-)  Take the sum of the squares of the absolute value of every equation in the universe and set it equal to zero.

Comment: @TerryTao: At the moment I care less about Lorentz invariance: after all, the Lagrangian $m\dot x^2/2$ of a free non-relativistic particle is not Galileo invariant, only up to total derivatives, although in relativity Lagrangians are usually Lorentz invariant as far as I know. The problem is that EL equation for this Lagrangian is of second order. I do not see immediately if it's equivalent to Maxwell equations. Probably not: how a system of linear second order equations could be equivalent to a system of linear first order equations?

Comment: There are analytic reasons (in this case, elliptic rigidity) that allow a second-order system to be equivalent to a first-order system given suitable boundary conditions.  The prototypical example of this is Liouville's theorem for harmonic functions, which shows that the second-order equation $\Delta u = 0$ is equivalent to the first order system $\nabla u = 0$ if $u$ is bounded.  More generally, the Euler-Lagrange equations for $\int \sum_i |L_i u|^2$ is $\sum_i L_i^* L_i u = 0$, which is equivalent to the system $L_i u = 0$ if $u$ does not grow too fast at infinity.

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equations of this functional will certainly yield the global minimum, i.e., the solutions of Maxwell's equations. However, a priori they will also yield other local minima, saddle points and maxima, which are incompatible with Maxwell's equations. I'd be surprised if those can all be excluded (but maybe they can) - my initial bias though would be to search for such a counterexample.

Comment: The functional is convex and quadratic, so (formally at least) cannot have any other critical points (just look at the variation with respect to homogeneous scaling, $(E,B) \mapsto (\lambda E, \lambda B)$).  Admittedly there is an issue with non-compact spacetimes in which the Lagrangian is formally infinite, but this should at least rule out exotic critical points that have suitable decay at infinity (again, this is in the spirit of Liouville's theorem as mentioned previously).

Comment: The scaling is a pretty good argument. So, to get around it, one would at the very least have to work with boundary conditions where the fields don't vanish, maybe in a box to avoid things being infinite. Since the Euler-Lagrange equations are second order, maybe one can arrange some fields with linear dependence on space and time in the box.

Comment: Ok, so unless I've messed up somewhere, the Euler-Lagrange equations of this functional are simply $\square f=0$, where $f$ is any component of either $E$ or $B$ ($E$ and $B$ completely decouple!). So you can immediately find a solution violating Maxwell's equations as soon as you allow for nonzero boundary conditions on some compact domain - say, set $E_x = x$, all other components zero ... or, you could have electromagnetic waves that consist of only electric field ...

Comment: This makes sense since the integral form of Maxwell's equations already imposes constraints on the boundary data so obviously one cannot hope to have any Lagrangian formulation of such equations without imposing a consistency condition.  But perhaps this is the only such condition: if one is working in say a spacetime cylinder and all the integral forms of Maxwell are assumed to hold at the boundary, this together with $\Box f = 0$ may be enough to recover Maxwell's equations in the interior as well.

Comment: Maxwell consistency conditions at the boundary, now that would be some advanced cheating, ha ha ... but yes, at least for Euclidean metric, it's immediately plausible that would work given the uniqueness statements one has for harmonic functions. For Minkowski metric, one loses the positivity properties of the operator ... so perhaps one last question for you - are there analogous uniqueness statements for the Minkowski d'Alembertian that immediately come to your mind, or might that be a worthwhile MO question I ought to ask?

Comment: It's going to be a nontrivial question but I suspect that the existing control theory (or scattering theory) results for the wave equation in a domain should be able to give a result of this form.  Also energy inequalities should tell us for instance that a (smooth) solution to the wave equation that vanishes on the boundary of a compact spacetime cylinder (or maybe a truncated light cone) should vanish in the interior, which should give enough uniqueness to ensure that solutions to the wave equation with Maxwell boundary conditions should in fact solve Maxwell.

Comment: Good, I'll post a question - thank you for the discussion!

Comment: Turns out this was already asked by our OP here, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360886/uniqueness-of-solution-of-the-wave-equation (a bit more specific on the boundary, but close enough, I think).

Answer (score 9):

The nature of the Maxwell equations (including their Lagrangian aspects) can be clarified by viewing these equations as part of a larger family of classical field theories in physics.  For simplicity I will focus on just four theories here:

1. Vacuum [classical Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_equations);
2. Abelian vacuum classical Yang-Mills theory with gauge group $U(1)$, aka the vacuum Maxwell equations;
3. The vacuum [Einstein equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations);
4. The vacuum [linearised Einstein equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity).

However one could vastly generalise the discussion if desired, by adding a source matter term to any of these equations, or by coupling with other field theories to obtain such classical field theories as Maxwell-Klein-Gordon, Maxwell-Chern-Simons, Einstein-Maxwell, Yang-Mills-Higgs, Einstein-Vlasov, nonlinear sigma fields (wave maps), etc..  One can also similarly discuss quantum field theories but I will not attempt to do so here.

These equations all describe the dynamics of one or more underlying geometric objects, expressible in local coordinates by tensors (which I will call the *primary fields*):

1. For Yang-Mills the primary field is the connection one-form $A_\alpha$ (whose components take values in a Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$).
2. For Maxwell the primary field is the vector potential $A_\alpha$ (whose components take values in ${\bf R}$).
3. For Einstein the primary field is the metric $g_{\alpha \beta}$.
4. For linearised Einstein the primary field is the metric perturbation $h_{\alpha \beta}$.

For coupled systems one could have more than one primary field, but here we focus on simpler models in which there is just one primary field in each theory.  From this primary field one can then create some secondary fields:

1. For Yang-Mills one can form the curvature tensor $F_{\alpha \beta} = \partial_\alpha A_\beta - \partial_\beta A_\alpha + [A_\alpha, A_\beta]$ (normalisation conventions can vary from author to author here).
2. For Maxwell one can form the electromagnetic field $F_{\alpha \beta} = \partial_\alpha A_\beta - \partial_\beta A_\alpha$.
3. For Einstein one can form the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma = \frac{1}{2} g^{\gamma \delta} (\partial_\beta g_{\gamma \alpha} + \partial_\alpha g_{\gamma \beta} - \partial_\gamma g_{\alpha \beta})$ and the Riemann curvature tensor $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta = \partial_\beta \Gamma_{\alpha \gamma}^\delta - \partial_\alpha \Gamma_{\beta \gamma}^\delta + O(\Gamma^2)$ (where I omit the precise nature of the quadratic term $O(\Gamma^2)$ for simplicity).
4. For linearised Einstein one can form the linearised Christoffel symbol $\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma = \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\gamma \delta} (\partial_\beta h_{\gamma \alpha} + \partial_\alpha h_{\gamma \beta} - \partial_\gamma h_{\alpha \beta})$ and the linearised Riemann curvature tensor $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta = \partial_\beta \Gamma_{\alpha \gamma}^\delta - \partial_\alpha \Gamma_{\beta \gamma}^\delta$.

These secondary fields are not unconstrained, but by their definition obey various Bianchi-type identities (as well as some symmetry and antisymmetry identities not mentioned here):

1. For Yang-Mills one has the Bianchi identity $D_\alpha F_{\beta \gamma} + D_\beta F_{\gamma \alpha} + D_\gamma F_{\alpha \beta} = 0$, where $D_\alpha = \partial_\alpha + [A_\alpha,]$ is the covariant derivative.
2. For Maxwell one has the Gauss-Faraday law $\partial_\alpha F_{\beta \gamma} + \partial_\beta F_{\gamma \alpha} + \partial_\gamma F_{\alpha \beta} = 0$.
3. For Einstein one has the second Bianchi identity $\nabla_\alpha R_{\beta \gamma \delta}^\sigma + \nabla_\beta R_{\gamma \alpha \delta}^\sigma + \nabla_\gamma R_{\alpha \beta \delta}^\sigma = 0$.
4. For linearised Einstein one has the linearised second Bianchi identity $\partial_\alpha R_{\beta \gamma \delta}^\sigma + \partial_\beta R_{\gamma \alpha \delta}^\sigma + \partial_\gamma R_{\alpha \beta \delta}^\sigma = 0$.

These identities are best thought of as geometric identities rather than true laws of motion, despite the fact that some components of these equations would involve a time derivative when viewed in standard coordinate systems.  (All of these Bianchi identities can be derived mathematically from the Jacobi identity $[\nabla_\alpha,[\nabla_\beta, \nabla_\gamma]] + [\nabla_\beta,[\nabla_\gamma,\nabla_\alpha]] + [\nabla_\gamma,[\nabla_\alpha,\nabla_\beta]]=0$ applied to the covariant derivative $\nabla_\alpha$ that is naturally associated to the field theory.)  In the case of Maxwell and linearised Einstein, the Bianchi-type identities can be expressed purely in terms of secondary fields, but in general we see that the Bianchi identities involve both primary and secondary fields.

To each of these field theories one can associate a Lagrangian which is typically expressed in terms of both primary and secondary fields:

1. For Yang-Mills the functional is $\frac{1}{2} \int F^{\alpha \beta} \cdot F_{\alpha \beta}\ d\eta$ (using an invariant inner product on ${\mathfrak g}$, and with $d\eta$ denoting the Minkowski volume form).
2. For Maxwell the functional is $\frac{1}{2} \int F^{\alpha \beta} F_{\alpha \beta}\ d\eta$.
3. For Einstein the functional is the [Einstein-Hilbert action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) $\frac{1}{2} \int R\ dg$ ($R = g^{\alpha \beta} R_{\alpha \gamma \beta}^\gamma$ being the scalar curvature).
4. For linearised Einstein the functional is the quadratic component of the Einstein-Hilbert action applied to an infinitesimal perturbation $g = \eta + \varepsilon h$; it has a moderately complicated form, see e.g., equations (6), (7) of [this paper of Menon](https://scholarworks.uark.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1501&context=jaas).

One can express these Lagrangians purely in terms of the primary field by expanding every appearance of a secondary field in terms of primary fields.  In the case of Yang-Mills and Maxwell one can also express the functional purely in terms of secondary fields, but this is a fluke that is not expected to occur for more general field equations.

By varying these functionals with respect to the primary fields (or with respect to the secondary fields using the Bianchi-type identities as constraints that produce Lagrange multipliers, in the cases where those Bianchi identities can be expressed purely in terms of secondary fields), one obtains the equations of motion as Euler-Lagrange equations:

1. For Yang-Mills the equations of motion are $D^\alpha F_{\alpha \beta} = 0$.
2. For Maxwell the equations of motion are the Gauss-Ampere law $\partial^\alpha F_{\alpha \beta} = 0$.
3. For Einstein the equations of motion are $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\beta - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\alpha \gamma} = 0$.
4. For linearised Einstein the equations of motion are $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\beta - \frac{1}{2} R \eta_{\alpha \gamma} = 0$ (with $R = \eta^{\alpha \beta} R_{\alpha \gamma \beta}^\gamma$ being the linearised scalar curvature).

In the latter three cases one can express the equations of motion purely in terms of secondary fields, but again this is something of a fluke that should not be expected in general (particularly when working with nonlinear theories). Note that in all four cases the insertion of matter into the theory would add a matter term to the Lagrangian and thus a source term to the equations of motion, but would not affect the geometric Bianchi-type identities, which highlights a key difference between the equations of motion and the Bianchi-type identities.

In all of these cases, there is also a gauge invariance that prevents one from observing the primary fields directly.

1. For Yang-Mills, one can replace the connection $A_\alpha$ by the gauge-equivalent connection $U A_\alpha U^{-1} - (\partial_\alpha U) U^{-1}$ without affecting the physical observables.
2. For Maxwell, one can similarly replace the vector potential $A_\alpha$ by the gauge-equivalent potential $A_\alpha + \partial_\alpha \lambda$ without affecting the physical observables.
3. For Einstein, one can apply a diffeomorphic change of coordinates to spacetime and to the metric $g^{\alpha \beta}$ without affecting the physical observables (the general principle of relativity).
4. For linearised Einstein, one can replace the metric perturbation $h_{\alpha \beta}$ by $h_{\alpha \beta} + \partial_\alpha X_\beta + \partial_\beta X_\alpha$ for any vector field $X^\alpha$ (which can be viewed as a linearised (or infinitesimal) diffeomorphism) without affecting the physical observables.

Because of this gauge invariance, it is initially tempting in all four cases to try to ignore the primary field as much as possible and try to formulate the physics in terms of the secondary fields (which tend to be much more directly physically measurable, being less affected by gauge transforms).  However, despite the fact that in some cases the primary field can indeed be expunged from the equations of motion and/or the Lagrangian, there is no *a priori* reason why the geometric Bianchi-type identities should then be subsumed into the Euler-Lagrange equations (though one can always do so artificially, as explained in my other answer).  The fact that the Bianchi identities and the equations of motion look so similar in the case of Maxwell's equations (when specialised to 3+1 spacetime dimensions) is a misleading red herring; once one sees how things work for all the other field equations one sees that these two systems of equations should really be treated as being of a very different nature.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, Sorry for being boring, but I think that here the same point I do not understand appears in an equivalent form. "For Maxwell the primary field is the vector potential $A_\alpha$..." In Maxwell case existence of the potential is not given in advance, its existence is not assumed (in the contrary to further Yang-Mills generalizations) but it is equivalent to what you called Gauss-Faraday law $div(\vec B)=0, rot(\vec E)=-\frac{1}{c}\dot{\vec B}$.

Comment: This law is not a mathematical identity like Bianchi identity, but a law of nature established experimentally. For this reason vector potential $A_\alpha$ cannot be considered as an a priori  given field, it is a consequence of (Maxwell) equations of motion. The fact that $A_\alpha$ is defined up to a gauge is not the main difficulty, I think. Thus one comes back to the same issue: part of equaitons of motion is replaced  by something else mathematically equivalent to a constrain.

Comment: It's a question of interpretation.  You are using the nineteenth century interpretation of classical electromagnetism in which the electromagnetic field is taken to be primary and the vector potential is secondary.  I am using the post-Yang-Mills interpretation in which the vector potential is primary and the electromagnetic field, *by definition*, is the curl of the vector potential.  The subsequent development of the laws of physics (e.g., the electroweak theory linking electromagnetism to the U(2) Yang-Mills theory of the weak force) has shown this is the more natural interpretation.

Comment: An analogy would be with the vorticity formulation of the Euler equations for incompressible fluids (in which the vorticity $\omega$ is the primary field and the velocity field $u$ is derived by an "empirical" Biot-Savart law) and the velocity formulation (in which the velocity field $u$ is primary and vorticity is, by definition, the curl of the velocity).  Mathematically the two formulations are equivalent, but the latter is more physically natural; vorticity is not naturally interpretable as independent field, but rather as a manifestation of a velocity field.

Comment: Similarly, nineteenth century classical electromagnetism is mathematically equivalent to U(1) Yang-Mills theory, differing mainly in their philosophical designations of which fields are primary and which are secondary.  You seem to accept that for Yang-Mills it is indeed the vector potential $A_\alpha$ which is the primary field, and the standard model very definitely interprets electromagnetism as a U(1) Yang-Mills theory, so if you accept modern physics then we should all be in agreement.

Comment: Basically, in the modern interpretation of electromagnetism the epistemology of the electromagnetic field has been redefined.  Classically, the EM-field was what one could observe through the Lorentz force law, in which case Gauss-Faraday becomes an empirical law of nature and the Lorentz force law is largely true by definition.  In the modern interpretation, the EM-field is defined as the curl of the vector potential; now Gauss-Faraday is a mathematical tautology and it is the Lorentz force law that becomes an empirical law of nature.

Comment: It's analogous to how with the modern definition of the meter, the constancy of the speed of light $c$ is no longer an empirical law of nature, but is true by definition.  On the other hand, the principle of relativity (that physical laws that involve the meter length unit are the same in all reference frames) acquires much more empirical content with this definition.  Ultimately the net physical implications of special or general relativity are not affected by this convention on how to define the meter, but the relative weight assigned to the two axioms of relativity are altered.

Comment: Basically, modern physicists believe so strongly in the second postulate of relativity that we have elevated it to the status of a tautology by arranging our definitions accordingly.  Similarly, modern physicists believe so strongly that electromagnetism is a U(1) gauge theory that the EM field is now defined in terms of that theory, in particular elevating the Gauss-Faraday law to the status of a mathematical tautology.  (This is a falsifiable viewpoint; the demonstration of existence of magnetic monopoles would definitely cause a rethink of this position. But this has not occured yet.)

Comment: I agree that defining EM-field to be a vector potential has an advantage that only in this form the theory has Yang-Mills generalizations, and thus electrodynamics can be considered as a special case of them. But still classical electrodynamics is in a sense deeper than non-abelian Yang-Mills theories: it has the Gauss-Faraday law which is not just Bianchi identity. This is a very non-trivial step to replace $(\vec E,\vec B)$ with vector potential; this step  is missing in more recent theories. This step I am trying to understand.

Comment: From the modern perspective, the deep and nontrivial fact is that electromagnetism is a U(1) gauge theory.  This fact, together with the Bianchi identity, completely explains the Gauss-Faraday law.  You are of course entitled to revert back to the nineteenth century perspective of viewing the Gauss-Faraday law as an ineffable empirical mystery and ignore a century of gauge theory if you insist, but I don't see the advantage in doing so.

Comment: With all respect due, I do not see how the modern Yang-Mills theory clarifies elctrodynamics, except emphasizing the differential geometric meaning of the potential to be a connection. In fact YM-theories were motivated by the electrodynamics. The YM Lagrangian imitates and generalizes the electrodynamics Lagrangian, but tells nothing new on it.

Comment: There is one key  difference between YM and electrodynamics: in the former potential is a part of definition of the theory, while in the latter it is consequence of a deep experimental fact -Gauss-Faraday law. Let me speculate that without this law potentials were not known to physicists, and no YM-theory would be discovered. Thus not YM explains electrodynamics, but vice versa, to certain degree of course IMHO.

Comment: You are confusing historical order of discovery of theories with physical causation.  Kepler's laws of planetary motion were deep experimental facts that directly led to Newton's laws of universal gravitation, but it is the latter that explains the former, not the other way around.  Now, previously unexplained empirical facts such as Kepler's second law are mathematical consequences of deeper facts, in this case rotational covariance (and Noether's theorem).  This is completely analogous to how the Gauss-Faraday law is now a mathematical consequence of the deeper fact of the U(1) nature of EM.

Comment: Furthermore, Yang-Mills greatly clarifies electromagnetism by introducing the principle of U(1) gauge covariance, which greatly restricts how the electromagnetic field can interact with the other forces of nature, and is a principle that has no substantial counterpart in the classical Maxwellian theory.  It is hard to conceive how one could have discovered or even stated the electroweak interaction without the Yang-Mills interpretation of EM, let alone the standard model.  (U(1) gauge invariance also explains many other aspects of EM, such as charge conservation.)

Comment: To continue the gravitational analogy, your original question is analogous to the question "Can Kepler's laws be expressed as an Euler-Lagrange equation without the gravitational potential?".  Perhaps this is mathematically possible by some artificial trick, such as the sum-of-squares trick in my other answer, but it is hard to see the point of asking such a question in view of the completely satisfying success of Newtonian gravitation in explaining Kepler's laws.  Similarly with Maxwell's equations and U(1) Yang-Mills theory.

Comment: Not that I confuse historical order with physical causation, but often I find historical explanations more intuitive. Newton's laws without Kepler's laws would look unmotivated to me unless they are verified in some other similar situations. I would not deduce them from Einstein gravity equations. The same notions can be understood in different levels. I asked why the electrodynamics Lagrangian looks as it is. You basically say: because it is a special case of YM-Lagrangian which explains remarkably well many physical phenomena and have non-trivial differential geometric properties.

Comment: I agree with that. But then why YM-Lagrangian works so well? It is the same as to say "it works because it works".  Sometimes this explanation can be accepted. But in this case I do not feel satisfied with it. I think YM works so well because it is similar to electrodynamics Lagrangian, and not the other way around. Moreover I think electrodynamics is more than just a special case of gauge theories. To appreciate that one can go back to 19th century. Why not?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple Lagrangian that yields the Maxwell equations upon variation, taken from [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343075/84967) (also by me) on physics.SE. The trick is to introduce [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Let
\begin{equation}
S[\chi,\tilde\chi,F,\tilde F]\overset{\mathrm{def}}=\int
\chi_\nu(\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} - J^\nu)+ 
\tilde{\chi}_\nu(\partial_\mu \tilde{F}^{\mu \nu} - \tilde{J}^\nu)\mathrm dx
\end{equation}

Variations with respect to $\chi$ and $\tilde \chi$ give you the Maxwell equations. Variation with respect to $F$ and $\tilde F$ give you
\begin{equation}
\partial_{[\mu}\chi_{\nu]}=\partial_{[\mu}\tilde\chi_{\nu]}=0
\end{equation}

The equations for $F,\tilde F$ and those for $\chi,\tilde \chi$ are decoupled so you can forget about the latter. The standard Maxwell equations are obtained by also taking the magnetic current to vanish, $\tilde J=0$. The general case with $\tilde J\neq0$ also allows the existence of [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), a fascinating subject itself.

This trick (and variations thereof) is used in proving [$S$-duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-duality) of Maxwell's theory, and generalizations e.g. in [Seiberg-Witten theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg%E2%80%93Witten_theory).

Comment: Thanks. It seems however that if one allows auxiliary fields, like your $\chi_\mu,\tilde\chi_\mu$, one can write any system of PDE as EL-equations. Maxwell equations are not unique in this sense.

Comment: @makt Indeed, it's a common technique for making an apparently first-order PDE an ELE; often, we add a total derivative, thereby unsubtly disguising what we did (although the motive may be e.g. ensuring hermiticity). When complex fields are involved, we can often use the conjugate, adjoint etc. as the multiplier, for much the same reason as $z^\ast$ can be treated as "independent" of $z$.

Comment: @J.G. : Do you have examples of physical interest? An example I am aware of is the (first order) Dirac equation say for a free particle. Its Lagrangian has no auxiliary fields or constrains.

Comment: @makt The Dirac & Schrödinger Lagrangians (the latter Galilean-invariant) use this conjugate-instead-of-new-auxiliary technique. I imagine this has also been done with Rarita–Schwinger. The Batalin–Vilkovisky formalism is an example with novel multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

The actual number of degrees of freedom of the electromagnetic field is 2, per point in 3-dimensional space. One can see this starting from the formulation in terms of potentials, which feature 4 components per point. Gauge invariance allows one to choose, for example, the axial gauge $A_3 =0$, reducing the number of components to 3; then, one furthermore sees that $A_0 $ is not in fact a dynamical degree of freedom, since the conjugate momentum vanishes (there is no time derivative of $A_0 $ in the Lagrangean). In effect, $A_0 $ acts as a Lagrange multiplier enforcing the constraint $\vec{\nabla } \cdot \vec{E} =0$. Indeed, one physically sees electromagnetic waves with only 2 polarization degrees of freedom.

Now, the formulation in terms of electromagnetic fields $\vec{E} $, $\vec{B} $ formally features 6 components per point, so these must be viewed as constrained variables, with 4 constraints. And indeed, stating that the electromagnetic fields are components of a closed 2-form is the most economical and symmetric way of stating such 4 constraints, as discussed by Denis Serre.

If we insist on keeping all 6 variables, as opposed to eliminating 4 of them by choosing a minimal, unconstrained set of generalized coordinates, then we need to implement the constraints using 4 Lagrange multiplier fields. In that respect, electromagnetism isn't quite that exceptional, compared to classical mechanics. Even if we tend to discuss mechanical examples in the Lagrange formalism of the second kind, since that is the most economical, of course also the Lagrange formalism of the first kind is available and instructive. So,
while we don't need the full 8 auxiliary fields introduced by AccidentalFourierTransform, we do need 4 Lagrange multiplier fields for the electromagnetic case.

And that is the point where we perhaps shouldn't let aesthetics get in the way: Returning for a moment to the formulation in terms of vector fields, one actually only has to introduce one new Lagrange multiplier field in addition to the 4 vector field components $A_{\mu } $, namely, a Lagrange multiplier field, let's call it $\lambda $, implementing the gauge choice. The other Lagrange multiplier comes from among the original fields themselves - it is $A_0 $, as discussed above! Now, is there really a good reason to allow for the variable $A_0 $, but not the variable $\lambda $? What is the difference, beyond aesthetics? What if we renamed $A_0 $ into $\kappa $?

Analogously, in the case of the formulation in terms of $\vec{E} $ and $\vec{B} $, is it reasonable to object to the introduction of additional Lagrange multiplier fields? After all, there really are redundant components - electromagnetic waves have only 2 polarizations. However, if we accept that Lagrange multiplier fields are natural and necessary in such a situation, then the answer is the standard electromagnetic Lagrangean supplemented with the 2-form constraint introduced via Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thanks very much. The answer contains the same point I am trying to avoid. From the physical point of view electromagnetic field has 6 degrees of freedom $(\vec E,\vec B)$. When you assume existence of potential $A^\mu$ you assume half of the Maxwell equations. So you consider them as constrains rather than equations of dynamics. The other half of Maxwell equaitons are considered as equations of dynamics. This division of Maxwell equations into two types seems to me to be mysterious and artificial. I have never seen it in other examples of constructing  Lagrangians in classical mechanics.

Comment: Formally I understand the argument, but I would like to understand if one can avoid it. It looks really ad hoc. I do not see any reason, other then the technical one, to distinguish a part of Maxwell equations from the rest.

Comment: Well, I would on the contrary say that, from the physical point of view, the electromagnetic field has 2 degrees of freedom. That is what is actually seen in electromagnetic waves! We're the ones who are inflating the number of components to 6. Of course, we have reasons to do so, related to the different ways we are able to observe electromagnetic phenomena. I don't think this is that exceptional - think of a mechanical object constrained to move on a circle of radius $R$ in a plane. We can and do choose at times to consider that in terms of variables $r$, $\phi $ with a constraint $r=R$ ...

Comment: ... and we do readily distinguish the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations into dynamical and constraint equations.

Comment: Probably I start seeing your point. But in that case why do not we consider all Maxwell equaitons as constrains and no dynamics equations? Why do not we choose any other subset of Maxwell equations as constrains? Is it just technical convenience? I have never seen that in literature.

Comment: Well there really are 2 degrees of freedom, so we can't view all of Maxwell's equations as constraints. Two of them must be dynamical. So the question is, how do we count the rest. Now, for each constraint, there should be 2 equations - one for the constrained field and one for the Lagrange multiplier. Now, like in the vector potential case, some of the fields may already act as Lagrange multipliers! Just by counting, I suspect that we only actually only need 2 new multipliers, whose E-L equations bring us to a total of 10 equations, 4+4 of which implement constraints, leaving 2 dynamical ...

Comment: ... this would also match Terry Tao's comment that at most 6 of Maxwell's equations can be obtained purely from a formulation in terms of $\vec{E} $ and $\vec{B} $ fields - meaning we need 2 explicit extra Lagrange multipliers to enforce the other 2 equations. The choices we make in organizing the fields and equations are suggested by the symmetries, most importantly, Lorentz invariance. So, I'd say that's more than just technical - but you are right, these are choices, and we could choose to express electromagnetism in much more convoluted ways.

Comment: @makt "I have never seen it in other examples of constructing Lagrangians in classical mechanics"... actually general relativity provides a good example.  If one wished to formulate GR in terms of the Riemann curvature tensor instead of the metric (much as Maxwell's equations are formulated in terms of the EM field rather than the vector potential), one would see a "mysterious and artificial" division into the "constraint" equations (Bianchi identities) and "dynamic" equations (Einstein), with only the latter having a Lagrangian interpretation (Einstein-Hilbert action).

Comment: Ultimately the apparent symmetry between the Gauss-Faraday and Gauss-Ampere components of Maxwell's equation, and the apparent fundamental nature of the electromagnetic field, is a fluke of classical electromagnetism that is not replicated in more sophisticated electromagnetic theories, in which it really is the vector potential (or, as I like to think of it, the connection on the electromagnetic U(1) bundle) which is the underlying physical field.  This can be seen either in quantum mechanical electromagnetism (Bohm-Aharonov effect) or in classical coupled systems like Maxwell-Klein-Gordon.

Comment: @TerryTao: As far as I understand, in GR  the curvature tensor is not enough to write Hilbert action $\int s_g dvol_g$: one has to use the metric $g$ to write the volume form.  Bianchi identities are neither constrains nor equations of motions, in my understanding. To get EL equation one varies the metric rather then the Riemann curvature tensor constrained by Bianchi identities.

Comment: @makt - in our current context, $\nabla \cdot B=0$ and $\nabla \times E = -\dot{B} $ comprise the Bianchi identities ...

Comment: @TerryTao: May I also add that the formulation of Bianchi identity requires the metric (Christoffel symbols), it is not formulated purely in terms of the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: Admittedly the nonlinear aspects of general relativity weaken the analogy with the linear equations of Maxwellian electromagnetism.  But one can easily repair this aspect of the analogy by coimparing Maxwell to linearised gravity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity) instead.  Now the Bianchi identities use the Minkowski metric instead of a variable coefficient metric, and similarly the Einstein-Hilbert functional will use the Minkowski volume element instead of one generated by a dynamic metric.

Comment: One can imagine as a thought experiment that the equations for linearised gravity (Bianchi+Einstein, expressed in terms of a tensor field $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta$) were discovered before the full Einstein equations.  It was observed that it was technically convenient to express this tensor $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta$ as the Riemann curvature of a "metric potential" $h_{\alpha \beta}$, but the equations could be written without reference to such a potential, so one might be led to the belief that $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta$ could be treated as an unconstrained tensor.

Comment: However, such a mindset would have hindered the ability to discover the full Einstein equations, or to discover more general equations of motion (e.g., Einstein-Maxwell, Einstein-Vlasov, etc.) in which gravitation is coupled with other physical fields.  As I said, the ability for Maxwell's equations to be expressible purely in terms of the curvature tensor $F_{\alpha \beta}$ (analogous to $R_{\alpha \beta \gamma}^\delta$) is a fluke (only shared by a few other linear field models such as linearised gravity) and is somewhat misleading as a guide to more general physical field theories.

Comment: p.s. linearised Yang-Mills is another excellent analogy for Maxwell; expressible by fluke in terms of the curvature 2-form, but most naturally thought of using the connection 1-form (and in particular has a Lagrangian formulation in terms of the Yang-Mills functional subject to the constraint of being the curvature of such a form, but no natural Lagrangian as an unconstrained 2-form).  Indeed Maxwell *is* Yang-Mills for the abelian gauge group U(1), which is automatically linear due to the abelian nature of the group.

Comment: Details are now given in a separate answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is in the paper below:

Anthony Sudbery (York U., England) Jul, 1985
[A Vector Lagrangian for the Electromagnetic Field](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/19/2/002) 1986 *J. Phys. A: Math. Gen.* 19 **L33**