# Finite propagation speed for non-smooth solutions to nonlinear wave equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, wave-equation

Consider the semilinear wave equation in $[0,t_0] \times \mathbb R^d$ :

$$\square u = \pm |u|^{p-1}u$$

With subcritical/critical power $1 < p \leq \frac{d+2}{d-2}$.

It is easy to show by energy method that any two $C^2$ classical solutions $u(t,x)$ & $v(t,x)$ with same initial conditions on $\{0\} \times B(x_0, t_0)$ will coincide on the backwards light cone $K(x_0,t_0) = \{(t,x) : 0 \leq t \leq t_0, 0 \leq |x-x_0| \leq t_0-t\}$ (c.f. T. Tao, Nonlinear dispersive equations, Proposition 3.3).

I've seen this property being used for solutions in energy space $C^0([0,T], \dot{H}^1 \times L^2)$. I guess one should be able to generalize the above proposition using some approximation argument but I could not find a reference with a proof.

My main problem is that the proof using energy method uses the fact that a $C^2$ classical solution is locally bounded. This does not hold for energy space solutions.

My second problem is that if $u(t,x)$ is an energy space solution, then we can approximate $u(0,x)$, $\partial_t u(0,x)$ and $\square u(t,x)$ by smooth functions $u_{0,n}(x)$, $u_{1,n}(x)$, $g_n(t,x)$, and get an approximate classical solution $u_n(t,x)$ to the inhomogeneous equation
\begin{align*}
\square u_n(t,x) &= g_n(t,x), \quad (t,x) \in [0,t_0] \times \mathbb R^d \\
u_n(0,x) &= u_{0,n}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb R^d \\
\partial_t u_n(0,x) &= u_{1,n}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb R^d
\end{align*}

but I don't know whether we can approximate $u(t,x)$ by classical solutions $u_n(t,x)$  solving
\begin{align*}
\square u_n(t,x) &= \pm |u_n|^{p-1}u_n, \quad (t,x) \in [0,t_0] \times \mathbb R^d \\
u_n(0,x) &= u_{0,n}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb R^d \\
\partial_t u_n(0,x) &= u_{1,n}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb R^d
\end{align*}

Any help or reference is welcomed.

Comment: My answer below side-steps your second problem. But using a similar argument using Strichartz inequalities, you should be able to prove persistence of higher regularity: that if you have an energy space solution with data in $H^k$, then the solution is also in $H^k$. Combining this with an approximation argument your second problem should also have a positive solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approach this dually using that for classical solutions the finite propagation speed holds. This argument is similar in spirit to [this answer of mine for low regularity uniqueness for the linear wave equation](https://mathoverflow.net/a/361009/3948).

### 1

First write $w = u-v$. Then you see that $w$ solves a linear wave equation of the form

$$ \Box w = G(u,v) w $$

where the potential $G(u,v) \lesssim |u|^{p-1} + |v|^{p-1}$. **Pretend now that $G$ is a smooth function of $(t,x)$.**

### 2

Suppose for convenience that $x_0 = 0$. You want to prove that $w(t,\cdot) |_{B(0,t_0 - t)} = 0$ for $t\in (0,t_0)$. So it is enough to show that $\int w(t,x) f(x) ~dx = 0$ for every $f\in C^\infty_c(B(0,t_0-t))$. We will try to do so using a duality argument.

Fix $T\in (0,t_0)$, and take $f\in C^\infty_c(B(0,t_0-T))$. Solve the wave equation
$$ \Box \varpi = G \varpi $$
with initial data $\varpi(0,T) = 0$ and $\partial_t\varpi(0,T) = f$. **Under the assumption that $G$ is smooth**, we have that $\varpi$ is a smooth function with compact support for all time. In fact, for $t\in (0,T)$ we have that $\mathrm{supp}~ \varpi \subset B(0,t_0 - t)$ using the finite speed of propagation for classical solutions.

### 3

That $w$ is an energy solution implies that the following identity holds for any test function $\varpi$:

$$ \int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Box w \varpi - w \Box \varpi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} w \partial_t\varpi - \partial_t w \varpi  \Big|_{t = 0}^T $$

Using the support property for $\varpi$ as derived above, you have that the right hand integral vanishes at $t = 0$ since $w,\partial_t w$ vanishes on $B(0,t_0)$. The integral at $t = T$ has only one term, and that is $\int w f$.

The left hand side however vanishes: since the two functions solve the same (linear) equation you have $LHS = \int Gw~v - w ~Gv = 0$.

### 4

The above works assuming that $G$ is smooth. In general, $G$ is not. Replace $G$ by $G_\epsilon$ through mollification. And replace $\varpi$ correspondingly by $\varpi_\epsilon$. Then it suffices to show that

$$  \int_0^T \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (G - G_\epsilon) w \varpi_\epsilon \to 0 $$

Let me do the critical case for convenience; the argument should be similar for the subcritical cases with some adjustment of the exponents.

Noting that $p-1 = \frac{4}{d-2}$, by Strichartz inequality, $G$ belongs to space-time norm $L^1([0,T]; L^q_x)$ for any $q\in [\frac{d}{2},d]$. And the mollification will converge in that norm. Since $w$ is energy class you have that it is uniformly bounded in $L^\infty_t L^{2d/(d-2)}_x$.

The Strichartz estimates together with Gronwell's inequality can be used to show that if $G_\epsilon \in L^1_t L^d_x$, then

$$ \|\varpi_\epsilon(t)\|_{\dot{H}^1} \lesssim e^{C(T-t) \|G_\epsilon\|_{L^1_t L^d_x}} \|f\|_{L^2} $$

This shows that $\|\varpi_\epsilon(t)\|_{L^\infty_t L^{2d/(d-2)}}$ is uniformly bounded on the time interval $[0,T]$. And hence the fact that $G-G_\epsilon$ converges to zero in $L^1_t L^{d/2}$ gives that $|\int w(T,x) f(x) ~dx | = 0$ after taking the limit.